Extremely loud headphone crack
When changing input source to headphones there is an extremely loud crack from both speakers. Changing input source away from the headphones creates a slightly less loud crack.
The same happens when not playing audio for a while, then playing audio, an extremely loud crack plays as it starts to play, and a slightly less loud one a few seconds after the playback is finished.
Also, when turning volume to 0 in settings, then turning it back up, the headphones no longer work, and the AUX cable needs to be unplugged and replugged.
4 cracks also happen on boot, with varying spacing.
The pop noise is extremely loud and painful.
Happens with all tested pairs of headphones from various brands. How loud of the crack is seems to vary slightly between headphone model.
Ubuntu 24.04, Gnome 46.
On Windows 11, there is one very faint pop which is barely audible on boot, and no crackling whatsoever when switching output.
